# Facebook Comments - Admin per page

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I have a website that has a collection of events and any member of the website can create & administrate their own events.

Each event basically has their own mini-site within the website with information, downloads, news items etc. I also have facebook comments on many of these mini-site pages.

What I want to do, is allow a member who has an event and is also logged in to my website using facebook login (i.e. I know their fb user id) to be able to administer any of the facebook comments within their own event mini-site.

So I guess what I am indirectly asking, is that if I add the `<meta property="fb:admins" content="{event_admin_fb_user_id}" />` to each of the event mini-site pages that a user owns, will they be able to **administer those comments and those comments only**? I.e. they won't be able to administer comments on another users event mini-site (or any other page on the site for that matter).

**UPDATE: Facebook comments feature request**

So what I'm asking for isn't currently supported. I have added a feature request for this which has been added to the "wishlist".

You can view and vote for it here:
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19276

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible.

Comment: Yeah, that's the conclusion that I'm slowly coming to. I have also asked on the facebook developer forums AND created a feature request for it. It would be a nice feature :-)

Comment: What I'm asking for isn't currently supported. See updated question for details.

Comment: @Sathya - done :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I'm asking for isn't currently supported. I have added a feature request for this which has been added to the "wishlist".

You can view and vote for it here: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19276

Once the feature request has been accepted and implemented I will edit this answer. Thanks!

Comment: The link no longer works